# What is the optimal way to use multiple turbo stream updates with partials in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails

multiple turbo stream update

```
render turbo_stream: [

turbo_stream.replace(:flash, partial: "shared/flash"),

turbo_stream.replace(:user_form, partial: "form", locals: { user: u/user }) ]
```

is this the correct way to do it?
I have tried it and it works its!
is there an official way or better to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one?

```
render turbo_stream: [
  turbo_stream.prepend(:flash, partial: "shared/flash"),
  turbo_stream.prepend(:user_form, partial: "form", locals: { user: u/user })
]
```